# Disk problem: Formatted before iso burn

Tags: installation, iso, dvd

I had a new dvd-rw disk that i formatted before trying to burn the ubuntu iso to. It game me an error that there was no recordable disk in the drive. Any ideas?

-- EDIT 20:06 09/11/2013--
***I couldn't get the image file to work and I had an extra disk lying around, so I successfully burnt that. If you have a better answer, it would be greatly appreciated.***
[Thanks for your help ;-) ]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your description is very vivid but I had this happen, so I'm assuming u tried to burn something and it isn't work right... So you have a semi-burn disk burnt. In order to help can I know what computer your own? ( windows-7, windows 8, Mac etc. )

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the super fast answer. Let's get down to business. I am currently running a Compaq Presario CQ71 with Windows 7 64 Bit and a DVD-RW drive built in.

Comment: Ok, so when you open up your Windows files. You should see a cd drive when a disk is in... When this happens sometimes your computer won't read the disk. Is your disk being read?

Comment: I can open the disk, and it shows 'Drag and drop files to burn to disk'. I tried moving a text document in and out and it copied successfully.

Comment: We'll in order to burn Ubuntu. Don't drag and drop.

Comment: So drag and place the Ubuntu desktop into your cd location. After it's in there right click Ubuntu an find "open with" and hover over it. An option saying "windows CD/DVD Burner" should appear. Click that and a new windows should open. A little box should be on that window somewhere, make sure it is on the removable cd click "Burn CD". It will ask to format your disk accept it. It should do a loaig process for about 5-10 minutes. If  during the process it says disk cannot be read, or any error occurs message me

Comment: I am right clicking on the iso file and selecting 'Burn to disk'. It opens a Windows 7 iso burner. I select validate disk when complete and then burn. My disk activates then ejects with the message noted in the question description. Hope this is a better description.

Comment: Much better, you have the right window open wait one moment please

Comment: Open the cd file and drag the Ubuntu.iso* to desktop. Then go back to cd file and right click Ubuntu and click delete. Then right click the cd rom itself and it should have a format options click it. Then on desktop right click Ubuntu.iso* and open the windows disk burner again. It will ask to format disk again ( even though disk is cleared it is reading a partial.file ) and it should work. If it ejects it again try this process once or twice more. It took my computer 3 times to read disk

Comment: [Looky](http://imgur.com/RdPqcdo)

Comment: Still having trouble?